# Making .htaccess more specific specially for subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say we have a page called a.php

`www.site.com/a.php`

We notice that somehow Google crawler tried to access 
`www.site.com/a.php/` which resulted the same page like `a.php`. Similarly all links from `a.php` is also accessed and indexed.

Lets say if there are 10 links within `a.php` as

```
    a1.html
    a2.html
```

I see google has also indexed:

```
    www.site.com/a.php/a1.html
    www.site.com/a.php/a2.html
```

Which is wrong as we already have the following in index:

```
    www.site.com/a1.html
    www.site.com/a2.html
```

We are also doing relative URL rewriting in `.htaccess`. I think this might be an issue.
Could you please help us how to overcome this issue in terms of stopping new erroneous URLs to get indexed using `htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule to remove trailing slash from non-directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]
```

Make sure this is your first rule.